# How to list updates using WordPress XML-RPC methods

Tags: xml-rpc

Can any one tell me how I can list the updates using WordPress **XML-RPC methods**, like how we list **posts** and **comments** using `wp.getPosts` and `wp.GetComments`. I searched for the methods but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's because there [isn't a method](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) - you'll have to [add your own](http://josephscott.org/archives/2008/11/adding-xml-rpc-methods-to-wordpress/)!

Comment: thanx for ur reply @TheDeadMedic, since i am into iphone development i dont have idea about php,,i got a brief idea to add method but dono how to do that in php, could u pls tell me how to retrieve **updates** from there database using php